# Rollback updated data in sql server table without using transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have updated all of the rows of a sql server table by mistake.

Since this was not part of a transaction I can't rollback, how can I revert it?

Comment: In Oracle we would use `flashback`... you could maybe consider restoring the database? Manual should be of help.

Comment: Hopefully you have been taking frequent Transaction log backups.  Depending on your sql server version, to restore to a point in time, you'll follow these instructions here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Stop new updates to the database.

Take a full backup to a new backup file.

Now take a transactional backup to a new file.

Now do a point in time restore. Choose the time before your accident.

You will lose all other events that happened since then.

If this is a production database then you should do a point in time restore to a new database then use an update statement to correct your incorrect data.

Good luck,  stay calm.

Comment: Just to note that point in time is only an option if your database's recovery model is set to "FULL". Of course, restoring other types of backup is also an option, depending on what backups you have, and if you can ascertain when the update was run.